# How to capture incoming emails on exchange before they reach transport agents?

Tags: email, exchange, dkim

I'm trying to debug why some inbound emails are failing DKIM checks. I'm running the latest version of Microsoft Exchange server 2019 on Widows Server 2022.

I have enabled pipeline tracing via the Exchange Management shell, and have set it to capture emails from a certain domain.
This is working fine and I can see two separate folders are created per email caught.
These folders then contain `original.eml` and then the incrementing SmtpReceive and Routing `.eml` files.

However, when I run the `original.eml` file against `dkimpy` (Python utility that can check the dkim signature of `.emls`) the actual DKIM signature differs from the expected - which suggests that the email's body or headers have been changed. (Note that the *exact* same email sent to another MTA server has the expected DKIM signature)

I am trying to work out when my Exchange server is altering this incoming email - since the DKIM signature fails on the `original.eml` this tells me it is happening somewhere before the transport agents.

Is there a way to view the `.eml` for an inbound email as soon as it reaches my exchange server?

Comment: If it is before transport agents, you may probably need to setup a firewall or gateway before Exchange.

Comment: "Original.eml: This file contains the original unmodified contents of the email message before it encounters *any* SMTP events or transport agents."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/pipeline-tracing?view=exchserver-2019
Do you have multiple Exchange Servers, Edge Servers, or Appliances in front of your Exchange Server that inspect or possibly modify the messages?

Comment: Also, can you share which headers are signed for the emails that are verified successfully and the ones that fail? That should give you a clue to what is happening. Also, DKIM can fail on multiple causes, can you share the failure reason, perhaps all authentication related headers?

Comment: I do not have any other Exchange/Edge servers infront of my main Exchange server.

I was previously under the impression that the Original.eml generated by Pipeline Transport Logging, was the email after it had already passed through the Front End Transport service - which can make alterations to incoming email messages - such as adding authentication information or inserting routing information.

As for the headers, I can't seem to see much difference between ones that pass or fail. 
Most use:
 DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=200608; d=phoenixcontact.co.uk;

Comment: As for the exact fail messages (generated by SpamAssassin)

0.1 DKIM_SIGNED
 Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily *      valid *  
0.1 DKIM_INVALID DKIM or DK signature exists, but is not valid

Comment: Also when I look at the headers of the original.eml I can see that a load of X-MS-Exchange-Organization-XXX headers have been inserted - presumably by my Exchange server, as these headers are not present in the same email sent to my private Gmail account.
This makes me think that original.eml is not the unedited email before it encounters any SMTP events or Transport Agents.

Comment: Are you looking at the pipeline trace for the Transport Service or the Mailbox Transport Service? By default, the Transport Service logs are stored at `%ExchangeInstallPath%TransportRoles\Logs\Hub\PipelineTracing` and those are the ones you want to examine.

Comment: https://practical365.com/exchange-2019-mail-flow-and-transport-services/ for a visual representation of the difference in transport services.

Comment: I can confirm that I am looking at the logs located in the path you have provided.

After much more investigation, I am starting to think the issue may lie with Content Transfer encoding.
It seems that inbound emails that are using 8Bit encoding / charset=utf-8 are being converted to Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable and this seems to be breaking the DKIM signature.

I am not saying this is definitely the cause of the issue, it's just what I'm suspecting at the moment.
If you have any comments on this hypothesis please do let me know. - Thanks.